# eShell Aliases – How to `grep` Forward Slashes

Tags: eshell, bash

In Bash, I have an alias of `ls -Ap | grep --color=always /$` that grabs the directories of the current directory, more or less.

That said, using the same as an alias in Emacs's eShell seems to not work, at all.

It keeps grabbing files, as well, that (as far as I can tell) don't even have forward slashes anywhere in their names.

Does the forward slash mean something to eShell that it doesn't for Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be something peculiar about how `eshell` interacts with `ls`, not `grep`.

I can confirm your example, which works fine in shell-mode or a terminal, produces long output in eshell, and includes files, not just directories. This is the same using the built-in versions of ls and grep, and also using the 'normal' versions from the operating system. That is, eshell provides its own versions of `ls` and `grep`, and if you want to use the regular versions you have to specify `*ls` and `*grep`.

For me, the output of your code, with the eshell or standard versions of the commands, produces output in columns. In normal use, `ls` outputs filenames in columns for interactive use, but one per line when used in a pipe. This convention isn't followed in `eshell` apparently. You can force the output to be one file per line with the `-1` flag, :

```
ls -Ap1 | grep --color=always /$
```

I find these little edge cases pop up regularly with eshell. shell-mode doesn't include the elisp tools that eshell does, but I find it less surprising, and so easier to use.

Comment: Ahhh; I knew the commands were different but, from what I could see from the output, it didn't look like eShell's `ls` was providing anything Bash's `ls` wasn't.

I'm so used to Bash showing the results in columns, every so often, that it didn't even occur to me that `grep` would read it that way, as well.

Thanks for the explanation! It was really good at teasing out the points of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

`eshell` is not "bash in Emacs", it is its own shell. If you want to use "bash in Emacs" use `shell-mode` (`M-x shell`) instead and Emacs will run 'bash' (really, your default shell) as a sub-process. If you want to use `eshell`, you'll need to change your thinking a bit. Arguments that are expandable wildcards are passed to their command as an elisp list (a la `("a" "b" "c")`) not a flat list (`a b c`). The easiest way to see this is to compare the results of `echo *` in bash and eshell.

```
bash$ mkdir foo; cd foo
bash$ touch a c; mkdir b d
bash$ echo *
a b c d
bash$

eshell$ mkdir bar; cd bar
eshell$ touch a c; mkdir b d
eshell$ echo *
("a" "b/" "c" "d/")
eshell$
```

Since `eshell` is lisp we can use a predicate to change the meaning of the wild card. (In this case only directories)

```
eshell$ echo *(/)
("b/ "d/")
eshell$
```

Now, about your alias in general. To "grab the directories of the current directory" I would instead use `ls -d */`.

```
bash$ ls -d */
b/ d/

eshell$ ls -d */
a b/ c d/
eshell$ ls -d *(/)
b/ d/
eshell$ ls -d *(^/)
a c
```

I highly recommend reading [Mastering Eshell](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell), [Eshell Functions / Dealing With Wildcards and Multiple Files](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellFunctions#toc2), and [EshellAlias](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias) as they explain these aspects of `eshell` much more clearly than I can.

Comment: I hame some Qs regarding the Mastering Emacs page: it says the order of evaluation is:- 1 A full filepath (e.g. /bin/cp) runs cp in /bin
2 Look for the command prefix, eshell-explicit-command-char (default is *), and if it is found then look for the command in the search path.
3 Look for a shell-defined alias (alias command)
4 Look for cp in the search path, $PATH (or eshell-path-env)
5 Look for a Lisp function named cp or the elisp function eshell/cp:  and I would say this is way wrong. Surely  4 & 5 are reversed?